# Currency conversion by lookup in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, vectorization

In the dataframe I have price, currency and the conversion rate to a base currency

`price | currency | GBP | EUR | CAD`

I would live to convert the price to a base currency by looking up the conversion rates.

Currently I use a lambda function but the performance is very low for large data

```py
df['usd'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['price'] / row[order.currency], axis=1)
```

What would be the best way to vectorise or improve this kind of lookup function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a much quicker solution.

```py
df['fx_rate'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['currency'])
df['usd'] = df['price']/df['fx_rate']
```

Comment: Indeed. Arithmetic operations like `div` can be vectorized to avoid rowwise `apply` looping. Alternative, functional form: `df['usd'] = df['price'].div(df['fx_rate'])`
`